# Query to get 2 columns in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm completely stuck on this bit of code and hoping someone can help. I have a database with one table called "pages" and it has 5 columns: id, file_name link_name, category, main_cat. Not sure if it matters but main_cat has type of tinytext and file_name is varchar.

```
id | file_name   | link_name   | category | main_cat 
1  | books       | Books       | books    | 1
2  | fiction     | Fiction     | books    | 2
3  | non-fiction | Non-Fiction | books    | 2
4  | music       | Music       | music    | 1
5  | alternative | Alternative | music    | 2
6  | country     | Country     | music    | 2
```

In my navigation menu(code below), I would like to have all of the main_cat(1) listed and then the sub-pages, man_cat(2) to show underneath. Here is the code I have, right now, I've tried many different ways including an inner join and left join but not matter what, I keep getting an error that says "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..."

```
<ul>
 <?php
   $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 1 ORDER BY link_name ASC ";
   $main_pages = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
   confirm_query($main_pages);
 ?>
 <?php
   while($mainpage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($main_pages)) {
 ?>
  <li><a href="/edit.php?<?php echo $mainpage["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $mainpage["link_name"]; ?></a>  

  <?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = {$mainpage["file_name"]}";
$sub_pages = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
confirm_query($sub_pages);
  ?>
  <ul>
  <?php
while($subpage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sub_pages)) {
  ?>
 <li><a href="/edit.php?<?php echo $subpage["id"]; ?>"><?php echo $subpage["link_name"]; ?></a></li>    
 <?php
}
 ?>
  <?php mysqli_free_result($sub_pages); ?>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <?php
}
 ?>
 <?php mysqli_free_result($main_pages); ?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: You call mysqli_fetch_assoc multiple times, which one is the one not working, the first one?

Comment: Yes, don't I need to call it twice, they're 2 different queries, I have a query for the main pages and then a query for the sub pages. The sub pages (second one) is the one not working. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your $conn defined?

Comment: The $conn is fine, it's in another file. I get results for $main_pages always and for $sub_pages only if I remove category = {$mainpage["file_name"]} but that should work...I'm not understanding why I can't query the db to pull $sub_pages that have category = file_name.

Comment: Proper [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (here, SQL statements) is more useful than any ad hoc schema and sample data format. Please use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT ... VALUES` for [samples](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is going to give you heartburn:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = {$mainpage["file_name"]}";
```

The problem is that the `"` characters around `file_name` are being interpreted as ending the string, and PHP is behaving unpredictably.  In other words, PHP sees this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = {$mainpage["file_name"]}";
      // ^ start string                                                    ^ end     ^s ^end again
```

Try one of these options instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = '{$mainpage['file_name']}'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = '".$mainpage["file_name"]."'";
```

Also, note the quotation marks around the variable -- unless `file_name` is actually a number, you need to enclose the data with quotation marks.

Finally, this probably goes without saying, but you really need to use prepared statements here.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my issue...I had a feeling it was the quotes that were doing it...I tried escaping them but must have had it wrong. I could do that too right, escape the quotes? And yes, I agree, prepared statements are a necessary.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you mean escape the quotes around `file_name`, no, that would cause a syntax error. Example: `$x = array('foo' => 'bar');
echo "test {$x[\"foo\"]}";` throws "**Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING on line 2"

Comment: Any idea why would this would be breaking if I moved it to a function.php page? `function cms_find_sub_pages () {
  global $conn;
  
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = '{$mainpage["file_name"]}' ";
  $sub_pages = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  confirm_query($sub_pages);
  return $sub_pages;  
 }
`

Comment: You are trying to use `$mainpage` in your function, but you don't define it in your function or use the `global` keyword to specify that you mean a global variable. This is a [variable scoping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem. Either change `global $conn;` to `global $conn, $mainpage;` or, better yet, pass `$mainpage` as a parameter to your function.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have connected the right database and your queries are syntactically correct

`$main_pages  = mysqli_query($conn, $query);` will return boolean if your `$conn` is not set up correctly or query syntax is wrong.

Hence when you fire `mysqli_fetch_assoc($main_pages)` it throws
"Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..."
as, `$main_pages` is boolean value.

Comment: Thanks. If the connection wasn't right, I wouldn't be getting any results at all But I do get results for $main_pages. What I'm not getting is results for $sub_pages where category = file_name...

Comment: If your connection is fine, then try to print the query and fire in phpmyadmin, the issue would be traced.

Comment: Change your second query as "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category like '". $mainpage["file_name"]."'";

Answer (score 0):

I think it is something to do with your second query, you may have it formatted wrong... I'm no expert but maybe someone else can edit if I have it wrong.

From this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = {$mainpage["file_name"]}";
```

To this:

```
$mainfilename = $mainpage['file_name'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category = $mainfilename";
```

Comment: Not sure how it should be written but try doing what I have edited above...?

Comment: The first option needs quotes around the data to work, and the use of `"` is causing problems, because `"` encloses the entire string. The second option is also missing quotes around the data.